# Full browser video, video ratio

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I'm trying to create a full browser width video similar to this example:

http://www.zendesk.com

Creating the full width responsive video is simple enough:

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/video/

My problem is the height of the video when the broswer is full width. The video is too tall and fills the whole of the screen.

It would be better if the video was a different ratio but I don't think that wouldn't work.

Is it possible to place the video in a container and give that a height that will mask part of the height of the video. I don't mind cutting some of the vidoe off.

Answer (score 0):

zendesk is using a CSS Flex Box Layout.  More at: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/19/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/

I bet your answer lies there.  From what I saw in the source I'd guess zendesk is hosting video in a container that is framed between two flex boxes.  Cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

Check out the Vide jQuery plugin. From my personal experience, its the easiest to play with with minimal fuss.

Because the plugin is responsive, it will constrain the video to the height/width properties of your container or wrapper.

Your best using height:auto; width:xxPX; with your container/wrapper CSS.

http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/